# Sending Active Admin email when creating new Active Admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin in my Rails Application. I have been able to set it up and use default user but I cannot add new User. When I go to Add New Admin User it lets me put in a username but never sends the email to setup a password. How does Active Admin send the default email out of a development configuration to be able to setup a password for my users?

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin, by default, uses Devise for authentication. If you enable `:confirmable` it'll email that user to verify the creation of their account. You can read details on enabling `:confirmable` on an existing setup here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users

Comment: This doesn't send the email. It is almost like Devise isn't setup to send the confirmation email in order to confirm the account.

Comment: Do you have ActionMailer configured?

Comment: I have an ActionMailer setup but I haven't configured it to work with Devise because I thought Devise used its own mailer